# how to avoid mutiple http call when using component driven development with Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

We are using Angular JS in our application and I think , Other the being client side MVC framework , one of other great benefit of angular is, support of component drive development. below is my angular code and it really simplify my client side code . however we are concern about number of http call made by angular to load these component's html page since each component's html is defined in his own html file and referred via. templateUrl and when browser load this page , angular make a multiple http call to load those pages . is there any way , we ask angular to avoid these multiple call and club them in one call ? appreciate quick response ..

```
 <div id="home-container" ng-controller="homeCtrl">

  <mars-breadcrumb
        on-breadcrumb-update="onBreadcrumbUpdate()" > 
  </mars-breadcrumb> 

  <mars-user-prefrence 
        on-change="onUserPrefrenceChange(newPreferenceMode)"> 
  </mars-user-prefrence>

  <mars-merchant-search 
        on-merchant-search="onMerchantSearch(se10)"> 
  </mars-merchant-search>

  <mars-summary-card > </mars-summary-card>

  <mars-google-map 
        on-map-marker-clicked="onMapMarkerClicked(marker)"
        on-map-clicked="onMapClicked()"> 
  </mars-google-map>

  <mars-merchant-info
        on-display="onMerchantInfoDisplay(merchantLat,merchantLng)"> 
  </mars-merchant-info>

  <mars-location-filter 
        on-city-change="onLocationFilterCityChange(event,item)"> 
  </mars-location-filter>

  <mars-category-container
      on-industry-change="onIndustryChange(event,data)",
      on-channel-change="onChannelChange(event,data)">
  </mars-category-container> 

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can scan all of your .html templates and put them into one file using [a plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache) via a [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) task (or [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/))  (or [bower](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache%20with%20bower)) . Using a build tool would make your life easier.

Comment: thanks for your response , this is what I was looking for  . we are currently using Maven so need to check if any maven plug-in provide option to do this otherwise I may need to start using gulp OR grunt as you suggested . thanks much !!

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about loading more html files you can simply specify the template inside the javascript instead of linking to the html file

```
app.directive('myTestDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: '<div>Template</div>'
  };
})
```

Comment: thanks for your response. the reason we want separate html is to have designer work seperaeratly on html design . including html content in Js file , we will lose that benefit . additionally we will need to take of single quote present inside html file which I think going to extra overhead on development team .

Comment: If you are using single quotes in your html you can surround them with double quotes instead. In terms of the HTML there isn't really a reliable way to group the calls together.

Comment: thanks for your response !! As of now , I'm going with the same approach but hope angular will provide some better way to resolve this in future .